# How best to structure code to download resources using AFNetworking and CoreData in iOS

Tags: ios, networking, core-data, multitasking, afnetworking

I first download a single index document using AFHTTPClient and record each record using CoreData. I then need to spin up a separate process to download each individual record. What's the best way to do this?

Is it reasonable to make a request for each resource and just let them complete? There may be a hundred or so.

Alternatively, I could load the first, submit a request, then on success load and submit subsequent requests.

I'm using CoreData to update the database which I presume means that I need to have a separate NSManagedObjectContent for each request?

I'm also curious to know, does AFHTTPClient perform callbacks on the main thread, or on the thread that initiated the request? I'd rather not have the main thread blocked performing CoreData I/O.

Comment: You will need to have a separate `NSManagedObjectContext` for your background thread (and each other thread as well). After receiving your objects from the network, put them into your background managed object context, then synchronize that context to the other managed object contexts in your app.

Comment: My understanding of cell network networking is that latency is your biggest problem--you you'll pay a time cost for each connection you make. If you can combine requests, you may get better network performance.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to downloading the resources you could use AFNetworking to queue them.

You might be able to use - (void)enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation of AFHTTPClient.

First create a singleton to hold your own AFHTTPClient like so:

```
@interface CustomHTTPClient : NSObject

+ (AFHTTPClient *)sharedHTTPClient;

@end


@implementation CustomHTTPClient

+(AFHTTPClient *)sharedHTTPClient {

  static AFHTTPClient *sharedHTTPClient = nil;

  if(sharedHTTPClient == nil) {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    // Create the http client
    sharedHTTPClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mybaseurl.com"]];

    });
  }

  return sharedHTTPClient;
}

@end
```

Then queue your requests like so:

```
// Store the operations in case the failure block needs to cancel them
__block NSMutableArray *operations = [NSMutableArray array];

// Add operations for url
for (NSURL *url in urls) {

  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  __block AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[CustomHTTPClient sharedHTTPClient] 
                                           HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
                                           success:^( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , id responseObject ){

                                             // Do something

                                           } 
                                           failure:^( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error ){

                                             // Cancel all operations if you need to
                                             for (AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation in operations) {
                                               [operation cancel];
                                             }

                                           }];

  [operations addObject:operation];    
}

for (AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation in operations) {
  [[CustomHTTPClient sharedHTTPClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

There is also enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:progressBlock:completionBlock: if you need   to monitor progress.

AFNetworking Project:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/

AFNetworking Docs:
http://afnetworking.org/Documentation/index.html